# Which market category does this sustainable product belong to?

Tags: marketing

I'm currently working on an assignment, which is making an export plan for a product aimed at Asia. However I can't define the market of my product.

My product is basically an artificial riverbank; a mat made of coconut fibers with pre-grown plants in it, which can be easily placed on riverbanks to add more green and biodiversity to the place. It's completely sustainable and meant for urban areas.

To export it, I need to find market info. I can't find the import value or any solid statistics to describe the market of this niche product. I basically want the definition of a market where there is a lot of info and statistics, which I can "relate" to this product.

Like for example: it's easy to find the import value for 'fruit' in Japan. To which category could my product belong to? (or is the closest to? outdoor plants,.. any ideas?)

- not even sure if this is the right forum to ask this stuff, but thank you very much anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm from Canada and I work on policies supporting "clean technology" development, but its a very nascent sector from a statistical standpoint.  Statistics Canada only recently formalized a (very imperfect) definition, and our federal export development branch politely puts your problem this way: "For most Canadian cleantech exporters, the ASEAN markets are remote and not well known. Companies who feel that these countries may provide export opportunities should consult with Export Development Canada and the Canadian Trade Commissioner Service."

If you want to do some tough research, I would use search terms like "clean technology", "environmental goods and services", "water management", "land reclamation", etc. But in short, you're coming up dry because there's very little out there.